# Cannot change element class with JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to change the class of an span element inside button using JS, the console shows the change in the class, but in fact the class does not change.

[image]

Element html:

```
<button
  type="button"
  :class="`btn btn-link link ${status === 'x' ? 'primary' : 'danger'} ${className}`"
  @mouseenter="switchText"
  @mouseleave="switchText"
>
  <span :id="first-button-id">
    sometext
  </span>
  <span :id="second-button-id" class="hide">sometext1</span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
const firstButton = document.getElementById('first-button-id')
const secondButton = document.getElementById('second-button-id')
if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
  if (this.status === 'x' || this.status === 'y') {
    firstButton.classList.toggle('hide')
    secondButton.textContent = 'sometext'
    secondButton.classList.toggle('hide')
    console.log(firstButton.classList, secondButton.classList)
  } else if (e.type === 'mouseleave') {
    firstButton.classList.toggle('hide')
    secondButton.classList.toggle('hide')
    console.log(firstButton.classList, secondButton.classList)
  }
}
```

I also tried to change through the console in the browser - ran into the same problem.

If it matters, the button is part of the Vue component

Comment: Why would you even use a method or classes for this? You can just conditionally display elements using v-if and use your mouse events to toggle a variable in data. Are you familiar with how Vue works?

Comment: @JHeth Of course, you are better at Vue, but the question is not how to do this with variable in data. If you have nothing to say on a given question - leave your advice to yourself. The question was not how this could be implemented in alternative ways.

Comment: It is hard to tell the reason without looking at the full code. May I ask why do you want to do it this way and not `:class="{hide: status == 'x' || status == 'y'}"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the method above, you could try getting the id of the element and changing the entire class accordingly by:

```
var element = document.getElementByID("element");
element.className = the_classname_you_desire;
```

OR

You could try getting the id of the element and adding the type of class accordingly by:

```
var element = document.getElementByID("element");
element.className += the_classname_you_desire;
```

Hopefully this alternative method works for your coding desire.